# Where is Offset option in Copy Rotation in Blender 2.92

Tags: rigging, constraints

I am watching tutorial and he checks Offset option in copy rotation so he can independently rotate that bone separate from Control bone, but there is no option in Blender 2.92

Comment: it looks like Offset is somehow allowed by default in 2.9, no?

Comment: It is not in the way it behaves on tutorial. But I managed to change "Mix" from Replace to After Original and it seems to work like Offset, but not exactly sure.

Comment: oh ok yes it may be available in the Mix menu